# What are the best practice (performance wise) for JS/React operations on JSON, math and loops?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, performance, optimization

Long story short:

- I have an application that works on a big array of JSON objects (60K+ elements)
- I have to perform some mathematic operations (compare, add, nothing major)
- I am doing it within few for loops (simplifaction at the bottom)

**Tech stack is simple:** firebase + react - for simplicity you can assume, there's no libraries outside of them. 
**The reasoning for these decisions:** I wanted to play with react and this was fun to start with. The performance is acceptable BUT I want to make it better + I want to learn how to do it the right way.

**Questions:**

- is there a way for me to optimise it on JavaScript? (multiple
  threads, better usage of the loops)
- what is the best practice to write fast and performant JS code that works on the big JSONs?

```
  for(let i=0; i<10;i++){
   for(let j=0; j<10; j++){
    for(let k=0; k<10; k++){
     doCalculations(bigArrayJSONS, bigArrays2JSONS, i, j, k) 
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Are you certain that the performance problem that you intend to solve is in the JS operations? Is it possible that it's actually React's rendering that's causing the performance problem?

Comment: @yqlim - To clarify - the performance is acceptable and it is ONLY for the math operations. This is more of a "can I do better, rather than I must do better" :) Hope that answers the question.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: This is far too broad of a question. "I want to make everything faster" is great, but there are no silver bullets in performance. Otherwise we'd all be pressing the "turbo button" and going home. You have to measure, try one thing, measure again. Did it get faster? No? Remove that attempt. Measure, try something else, measure again...

Comment: ... that said, there are many other considerations e.g. "Do n users see the same calculated data?" In that case, doing that calculation on the serverside might be more efficient (as you can cache, and you might save bandwith when transfering data to the clients). Also the amount of data is quite relevant: Is it actually worth it to move it to another agent when transferring the data takes longer than the actual calculation?

Comment: @HereticMonkey - lesson learnt! :) Thank you. As for the performance - that's a very good comment. The problem is I am not sure where to start to be honest. I was hoping for an article on how to start and what are the most common pitfalls.
Still - point taken - I will be playing with some of mine ideas :)

Comment: @JonasWilms - The main point of this exercise for me was to not use backend - and push the whole logic into the frontend customer. 
I am not sure if I understand the question about transferring the data, do you mind clarifying/expanding it a bit for me?

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on what kind of problem you are solving using the loops.
If your array can be divided into segments 60k into 20k * 3, try processing each of the section using a web worker.

Refernce - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API

Comment: I was thinking more about splitting the loops rather than the arrays TBH. 
Will investigate - do you have any good resources with the web workers handling loops?

Comment: Here it is - https://itnext.io/achieving-parallelism-in-javascript-using-web-workers-8f921f2d26db. If this helps

Comment: Will it be faster to move the data onto three WebWorkers? Why three and not four? This is really more a comment than a real answer to the question (which will either be very long, or it can't be answered at all)